# Auto-completion in Click does not work outside virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a Python script that is designed to make some basic text edits and accepts command line parameters. The whole project is enclosed in a virtual environment too.

I am using python Click module to accept command line parameters, which does support [auto completion in bash](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/shell-completion/). I have a basic setup.py file to install the main script as a command or in a virtual environment by using `pip install --editable .`.

Now let's say main script is called `edits`. I should use `_EDITS_COMPLETE=bash_source edits` to generate a bash script to be run and enables auto completion. This does work fine in a virtualenv, where the script gets generated. However, outside of it, the normal script output is given.

In another words, in virtualenv the script returns the correct auto complete script, but outside of it, nothing happens.

So where may the issue with this be? I expect it to generate auto complete script outside virtualenv too.

Link to repository with the script I am trying to use: https://github.com/Astra3/DiscordText

Comment: Please provide sample code, commands run, and output. Without that, the best we can do is guess. From the Click documentation: "Completion is only available if a script is installed and invoked through an entry point, not through the python command." Are you installing on the host environment before trying to run outside of the virtualenv?

Comment: @jisrael18 I can provide access to the whole repository on GitHub, I'll just update the main post. And yes, I am installing it on the host environment before trying to run completion.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install click` (or `pip install -r requirements.txt`) in our host environment (outside the virtual env) and it will work.